# Get the size of a Sub Folder/Sub Directory excluding the Parent Folder

Tags: vb.net, listview

i have a listview that shows folders and files, and i can display the size of the files and subfolders, but how do i do it with subfolders only not including the parent/root folder.

**EDIT**

like, if `Folder1`'s size is `10 MB` and it has a `SubFolder` with `20 MB` size with a total of `30 MB`, it should only get the size of the `SubFolder` which is `20 MB` when displaying the contents of the `Folder1` in a `ListView`.

```
Public Shared Function DirSize(ByVal d As DirectoryInfo) As Long
    Dim Size As Long = 0

    Dim dis As DirectoryInfo() = d.GetDirectories()
    Dim di As DirectoryInfo
    For Each di In dis
        Size += DirSize(di)
    Next di
    Return Size
End Function
```

my listview code:

```
Sub lv1items()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim fPath As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
    Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(fPath)

    ' store imagelist index for known/found file types
    Dim exts As New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)

    If di.Exists = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Destination path" & " " & Form2.TextBox1.Text & " is not found.", "Directory Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Form2.Show()
    Else
        Dim img As Image
        Dim lvi As ListViewItem
        For Each d In di.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            lvi = New ListViewItem(d.Name)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(DirSize(di).ToString("0.00") & " MB")
            lvi.SubItems.Add(d.CreationTime.Date)

            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

            img = NativeMethods.GetShellIcon(d.FullName)
            ImageList1.Images.Add(img)
            lvi.ImageIndex = ImageList1.Images.Count - 1
        Next
End Sub
```

it returns a 0 size folder, but it has a file inside.[image]

a little help please?

Comment: You have to sum the files inside - folders themselves do not have a size

Comment: @user2041732. Sorry i didn't notice that this is vb.net. I have fixed my answer now. Please check it out.

Comment: how do i do that with a subfolder? i mean not the one that i'm inside of, in a `ListView`, or not the one declared as a `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: If you have `FoldA\SubB\SubC`, do you want `FoldA` to include the files in B and C?  Then B also includes C?

Comment: uhm the size of B and C only, not including the `FoldA`.

Comment: @user2041732 If you want only the subfolder, then why bring in to play, the parent folder? Call the function directly on the sub folder. If you don't know the names of the sub folders, or they are variable, use the [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx) function and call it on each of the returned directories. Add up the size of each returned sub folder and you should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Having a folder show the size of the child folders and *not* the size of the files in itself, seems confusing.  The view doesnt tell you anything about the current one (FoldA), but something else; and if it has more than 1 sub folder, you never see the size of them.

Comment: does it mean it's not possible?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ because when I'm viewing the files and subfolders of a Parent Folder in a `ListView`,  I have to declare it as the `DirectoryInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function GetDirectorySize(path As String) As Long
    Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim size As Long = 0
    For Each file As String In files
        Dim info As New FileInfo(file)
        size += info.Length
    Next
    Return size
End Function
```

Note that this checks the size of every file in the folder and its subdirectories. Thus it is guaranteed to return the correct size.

Proof that it works:

Root:

[image]

SubFolder:

[image]

Total Size = (1483 + 25315) * 1024 = 274411152 bytes.

Program Output:

[image]

27440016 bytes ≈ 274411152 bytes.

**Note:** *The difference exists because Windows Explorer rounds off some bytes to display the KB. If you view the properties of each file and add up then you will get the same size from both Explorer and the function.*

Comment: this code displays the files' size of the current folder that i'm inside of(D:\Test), not the subfolder(D:\Test\Folds), like in the image.

Comment: @user2041732 Wait. let me look into this.

Comment: @user2041732 See the edit please. It works good enough :) Make sure you are calling it correctly.

Comment: uhm what i meant was the size of the subfolder only, not including the root folder.